# Mystery left padding from a horizontal ul list

Tags: html, css

I have made a horizontal unordered list that works great except for the fact that there is some left padding. I'd like the UL to be flush against its' container and not have any padding.

I've tried margin-left: 0 but no joy.

Can anyone see or think of a way to get my markup to be flush left?

```css
ul.speakerclass > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* You can also add some margins here to make it look prettier */
    width:180px;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    /* this fix is needed for IE7- */
}

.speakercard {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

button.speakerclass {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #393939;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

a.speakerclass {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

button.speakerclass:hover, a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.speaker-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.speaker-pic {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="speakerclass">
  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="speaker-box">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="speaker-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>1 Psoo Doe</p>
      <p><button class="speakerclass">Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="speaker-box">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="speaker-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>2 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="speaker-box">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="speaker-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>3 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
ul.speakerclass {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: yes good idea and the issue seems to be my WordPress theme has some sort of default 40px left padding for ul

Answer (score 1):

Setting `padding-left: 0` for the `ul.speakerclass` container removed the space.

According to [W3C Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#lists), `<ul>` elements by default have a `padding-inline-start: 40px`. This accounted for the 40px of left padding.

```css
ul.speakerclass {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul.speakerclass > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* You can also add some margins here to make it look prettier */
    width:180px;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    /* this fix is needed for IE7- */
}

.speakercard {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

button.speakerclass {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #393939;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

a.speakerclass {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

button.speakerclass:hover, a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.speaker-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.speaker-pic {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="speakerclass">
      <li>
        <div class="speakercard">
          <div class="speaker-box">
            <img src="./img.jpeg" class="speaker-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <p>1 Psoo Doe</p>
          <p><button class="speakerclass">Speaker Profile</button></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="speakercard">
          <div class="speaker-box">
            <img src="./img.jpeg" class="speaker-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <p>2 Doe</p>
          <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="speakercard">
          <div class="speaker-box">
            <img src="./img.jpeg" class="speaker-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <p>3 Doe</p>
          <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```